# Datos día a día

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes datos:

Cantidad - Fecha

1 - 2018-04-25

1 - 2018-04-25

1 - 2018-04-26

1 - 2018-04-28

Al momento de realizar una consulta y agrupar por dias me aparece:

resultado de la consulta:

2 - 2018-04-25

1 - 2018-04-26

1 - 2018-04-28

y quiero que me muestre:

2 - 2018-04-25

1 - 2018-04-26

0 - 2018-04-27

1 - 2018-04-28

El dato del 2018-04-27 no existe en la base de datos, pero necesito visualizarlo en cero "0" es decir ver dia a día la cantidad sumada

Agradeciendo la colaboración

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Crear una función que regrese el rango de días que deseas obtener
2. Hacer uso del query que existe en esta solución, tomando en cuenta los valores mínimo y máximo de tu consulta de información. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range

Personalmente validé el query que se muestra en la solución y funciona muy bien, aunque repito, deberás ingresar las fechas mínimas y máximas de tu información. Todo es posible dentro de un mismo query.

Answer (score 0):

podría agregar el resultado de tu query a un array para luego validarlo en un bucle, algo así:

```
    //Resultado de la query
$query = array("2018-04-25"=>"2","2018-04-26"=>"1","2018-04-28"=>"1");

//
Fecha de inicio
$inicia = "2018-04-01";
//Rango de extension de busqueda
$dias = 30;

//Iniciamos la validación
for($i=1; $i<=$dias; $i++){
    $temp = $inicia;
    if( array_key_exists($temp,$query)){
        echo $temp.' -> '. $query[$temp]."<br>";
    }else{
        echo $temp." -> 0<br>";
    }
    $tempb = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($temp));
    $inicia = date("Y-m-d", $tempb);
}
```

esto nos retorna este resultado:

```
2018-04-01 -> 0
2018-04-02 -> 0
2018-04-03 -> 0
2018-04-04 -> 0
2018-04-05 -> 0
2018-04-06 -> 0
2018-04-07 -> 0
2018-04-08 -> 0
2018-04-09 -> 0
2018-04-10 -> 0
2018-04-11 -> 0
2018-04-12 -> 0
2018-04-13 -> 0
2018-04-14 -> 0
2018-04-15 -> 0
2018-04-16 -> 0
2018-04-17 -> 0
2018-04-18 -> 0
2018-04-19 -> 0
2018-04-20 -> 0
2018-04-21 -> 0
2018-04-22 -> 0
2018-04-23 -> 0
2018-04-24 -> 0
2018-04-25 -> 2
2018-04-26 -> 1
2018-04-27 -> 0
2018-04-28 -> 1
2018-04-29 -> 0
2018-04-30 -> 0
```